# How to use jq in ansible shell tasks

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use jq command in ansible playbook, facing issue while running shell command

```
---
- name: shell
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    hbawwn_statement: '{ "HBA WWN" : "Pass" , "Result" : "a\nb" }'
    arrayno_statement: '{ "Storage Array Number" : "Pass" , "Result" : "0001a\n0001b" }'
    adapterslot_statement: '{ "Host Adapter Slot" : "Pass" , "Result" : "PCI Slot 3\nPCI Slot 2" }'
    adaptertype_statement: '{ "Host Adapter Type" : "Pass" , "Result" : "AJB/AHA\nAJB/AHA" }'


  tasks:
    - name: test
      set_fact:
        sk_out: "[{{ adaptertype_statement }}, {{ adapterslot_statement }}, {{ arrayno_statement }}, {{ hbawwn_statement }}]"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ sk_out }}"
    - name: jq command
      shell: {{ sk_out }} | jq 'map_values(.Result | split("\n")) | transpose | map( {"Host Adapter Type":.[0], "Host Adapter Slot":.[1], "Storage Array Number":.[2],"HBA WWN":.[3]})' | jq -n '."CUT Sheet " |= [inputs]'
      register: out
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ out.stdout }}"
```

Getting error
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
expected a comment or a line break, but found 'j'\

The error appears to be in 'test_jq.yml': line 22, column 29, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
- name: jq command
  shell: {{ sk_out }} | jq 'map_values(.Result | split("\n")) | transpose | map( {"Host Adapter Type":.[0], "Host Adapter Slot":.[1], "Storage Array Number":.[2],"HBA WWN":.[3]})' | jq -n '."CUT Sheet " |= [inputs]'
                        ^ here
```

We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

```
TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "Host Adapter Type": "Pass", 
            "Result": "AJB/AHA\nAJB/AHA"
        }, 
        {
            "Host Adapter Slot": "Pass", 
            "Result": "PCI Slot 3\nPCI Slot 2"
        }, 
        {
            "Result": "0001a\n0001b", 
            "Storage Array Number": "Pass"
        }, 
        {
            "HBA WWN": "Pass", 
            "Result": "a\nb"
        }
    ]
}
```

verified copying the content of {{ sk_out }} into a txt file
s.txt

```
[
        {
            "Host Adapter Type": "Pass", 
            "Result": "AJB/AHA\nAJB/AHA"
        }, 
        {
            "Host Adapter Slot": "Pass", 
            "Result": "PCI Slot 3\nPCI Slot 2"
        }, 
        {
            "Result": "0001a\n0001b", 
            "Storage Array Number": "Pass"
        }, 
        {
            "HBA WWN": "Pass", 
            "Result": "a\nb"
        }
    ]
```

output

```
cat s.txt | jq 'map_values(.Result | split("\n")) | transpose | map( {"Host Adapter Type":.[0], "Host Adapter Slot":.[1], "Storage Array Number":.[2],"HBA WWN":.[3]})' | jq -n '."CUT Sheet " |= [inputs]'\
```

this command working
tried to add brackets like shell: "{{ sk_out }}" | jq  but this is not working syntax error.
How to handle this in ansible playbook without creating txt file.

Comment: Quote the entire command (and escape quotes accordingly), not just the jinja2 expression at start. Note also that bash will error if you simply output your var (i.e. command not found) rather than using e.g. `echo` to pass it to next jq in pipe.

Comment: Or take advantage of the fact that jq reads from stdin with [`args: stdin: "{{ sk_out }}"`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/shell_module.html#parameter-stdin)

Answer (score 1):

Whilst zeitounator and mdaniel appraisals of the problem were quite correct, instead of adding yet another pair of quotes around the already quotes-crowded expression, I'd recommend using the `>` YAML construct:

```yaml
...
    - name: jq command
      shell: >
        echo "{{ sk_out }}"
        | jq 'map_values(.Result | split("\n")) | transpose | map( {"Host Adapter Type":.[0], "Host Adapter Slot":.[1], "Storage Array Number":.[2],"HBA WWN":.[3]})'
        | jq -n '."CUT Sheet " |= [inputs]'
      register: out
...
```

I believe that makes your code easier to read and maintain.

That said, this dictionary (or mapping, or hash-table, or associative arrays, whatever you call it) manipulation can be performed inside ansible itself, there is no need to go `shell`+`jq` on that. Take a look at the Ansible filters:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html

And also at the Jinja2 (templating engine) built-in filters:

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters

HTH

Alex

Comment: This yaml construct made my code really readable at last. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but as an example of something that might be half-way through to what you want, you could:

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      stmt_keys: "{{ stmt_keys|d([]) + [(item|list|reject('equalto', 'Result')|list)[0]] }}"
      stmt_results: "{{ stmt_results|d([]) + [item['Result'].split('\n')] }}"
    loop: "{{ sk_out }}"

  - set_fact:
      alt_out: "{{ stmt_keys | zip(stmt_results) | list }}"

  - name: non-jq command
    debug:
      msg: alternate={{ item }}
    loop: "{{ alt_out }}"
```

That generates the output:

```
...

TASK [non-jq command] *****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Host Adapter Type', ['AJB/AHA', 'AJB/AHA']]) => {
    "msg": "alternate=['Host Adapter Type', ['AJB/AHA', 'AJB/AHA']]"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Host Adapter Slot', ['PCI Slot 3', 'PCI Slot 2']]) => {
    "msg": "alternate=['Host Adapter Slot', ['PCI Slot 3', 'PCI Slot 2']]"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Storage Array Number', ['0001a', '0001b']]) => {
    "msg": "alternate=['Storage Array Number', ['0001a', '0001b']]"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['HBA WWN', ['a', 'b']]) => {
    "msg": "alternate=['HBA WWN', ['a', 'b']]"
}
```