# How can I pass a json variable set by set_fact to jq pipeline in ansible shell task?

Tags: json, ansible, jq

I have a ansible playbook that has set a json variable using `set_fact` module.
I'm trying to use jq command in ansible playbook, to transform that json to a particular format, but got parse error: `Invalid numeric literal at line , column`

My Playbook:

```
- name: get data
  set_fact:
    data: "{{ value.stdout | from_json }}"

- name: get key value pairs
  shell:  echo "{{ data }}" | jq 'to_entries | map((.key) + "=" + .value)|join(",")'
  register: key_value
```

Error:

```
TASK [utils : debug] *************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "data": {
        "key1": "keyval1",
        "key2": "keyval2"
    }
}

TASK [utils : get key value pairs] ***************************************************************
FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo \"{'key1': 'keyval1', 'key2': 'keyval2'}\" | jq 'to_entries | map((.key) + \"=\" + .value)|join(\",\")'", "stderr": "parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line , column", "stderr_lines": ["parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line , column"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

PS: I had tried using > YAML construct specified in [How to use jq in ansible shell tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64045520/how-to-use-jq-in-ansible-shell-tasks/64057402#64057402) but got same error

```
- name: get key value pairs
  shell:  >
     echo "{{ data }}" 
     | jq 'to_entries | map((.key) + "=" + .value)|join(",")'
  register: key_value
```

My `data` variable set using `set_fact` module:

```
"data": {
        "key1": "keyval1",
        "key2": "keyval2"
}
```

Working jq command and expected output: [jqPlay](https://jqplay.org/s/x6hnhPBQUmf)

How can I pass the fact variable set using `set_fact` to jq pipeline in ansible?

Comment: This isn't an issue with jq, but how you pass the JSON content using the ansible shell module to jq. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64057402/5291015) for one such way to solve the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use jq in ansible shell tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64045520/how-to-use-jq-in-ansible-shell-tasks)

Comment: ```shell:  >
    echo "{{ data }}"
    | jq 'to_entries | map((.key) + "=" + .value) | join(",")'``` even this gives the same error.

Comment: `{'key1': 'keyval1'}` isn't valid JSON (printed in error message). JSON only allows double quotes around keys and strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error seems to be jq complaining about the JSON passed to it. As mentioned by
@knittl the json printed in error message isn't valid JSON.
Somehow double quotes were replaced by single quote although debug prints valid JSON. Invalid JSON was passed to jq.

Replacing the single quote with double quote solved the issue.

```
shell: echo "{{ data | to_json }}"| jq 'to_entries | map((.key) + "=" + .value)|join(",")'
```

or

```
shell: echo "{{ data }}" | sed "s/'/\"/g" | jq 'to_entries | map((.key) + "=" + .value)|join(",")'
```

PS: This is just a working solution not the ideal one!